# B-Tree Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

I was reading about implementing B-Tree from Rober Sedgewik's and found this snippet in the `else` part of `search` method from this link: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/62btrees/BTree.java.html

```
// internal node
        else {
            for (int j = 0; j < x.m; j++) {
                if (j+1 == x.m || less(key, children[j+1].key))
                    return search(children[j].next, key, ht-1);
            }
        }
```

I banged my head but couldn't understand why he directly starts comparing `key` with `j+1`th element of `children` and not `j`th. 
Could someone please through some light upon this specific point?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at his declaration of the `less()` method, you'll notice that it uses `compareTo`.

Essentially, what he wanted to do was `key.compareTo(children[j+1].key)`

But why would he use `j+1` instead of `j`? To understand this, look at the first part of his conditional statement; he uses `j+1 == x.m`, meaning that he wants to test to see if j+1 is the limit. If `j+1 = x.m`, he doesn't want to continue incrementing j, so he returns. However, if it is not the limit yet, check compare the current key with the next key in the list (because the next key exists). IF the next key in the list is "less" than the current key, search for the current key.

In short:
If `j+1` doesn't exist, the first half of the if statement will catch it and it will break out of the `for` loop. Otherwise, check `j+1`'s key.

Comment: Right, I got it. But in doing so, isn't he NOT COMPARING key with the `j`th element at all? I was wondering what if the `key` of the `j`th element itself is greater than `key`? He shouldn't even go to `j+1`th then, right?

Comment: I don't think he's trying to compare with j. If you read the rest of the search function, it's an if-else statement, which leads me to assume that the comparison of j is done in the "if statement". The "else" part (the part that you posted) is just there to make sure that he doesn't get a NPE (if there is no next value)

Comment: Well actually, the `if` condition is for the leaf nodes (`if(ht==0)`) and `else` for internal nodes. Also, note that in that `if` block, he checks from `j=0`.

Comment: I stand by my answer that it's checking for NPE; it's a tree, and as such it is made up of by smaller trees. This function is a recursive function, so he needs to check to make sure that the internal isn't null, before calling search on the child (which will itself check j, not j+1)

Comment: Actually, finally figured it out! It's because in a B-Tree, none of the nodes except the leaf nodes carry any information. They just act as separators. So, that separator will be the first child in the children's entry. So, it need not be searched!

Comment: Nice! Close enough on my end :P